# Show several Instagram accounts (10 images/account) on one 1 page

Tags: php, mysql, instagram-api

I'm having several names and access tokens stored in my MySql database and I want to display images for those users.

I have found a library online and it works great. I'm testing my account and so far so good. But the problem appears when I'm display all accounts.
It's just showing latest account added..
While loop is working great to fetch data from MySQL but the problem comes when I add this Instagram code.

Here is the code:
lib/instagram_single.php

```
<?php
class InstaWCD{


function userID(){
    $username = strtolower($this->username); // sanitization
    $token = $this->access_token;
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=".$username."&access_token=".$token;
    $get = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($get);

    foreach($json->data as $user){
        if($user->username == $username){
            return $user->id;
        }
    }

    return '00000000'; // return this if nothing is found
}

function userMedia(){
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$this->userID().'/media/recent/?access_token='.$this->access_token;

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
      return $json = json_decode($content, true);
}

}
 $insta = new InstaWCD();
    $insta->username = $username;
    $insta->access_token = $access_token;
?>
```

And the code I'm trying to run.

```
    <?php

    
    
        $statement = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT v2_instagram_users.user_id, v2_instagram_users.instagram_id, v2_instagram_users.username, v2_instagram_users.Name, v2_instagram_users.Bio, v2_instagram_users.instagram_access_token, users.user_name, users.user_age, users.country, users.gender, users.gender_search, users.age_from, users.age_to
        FROM v2_instagram_users, users 
        WHERE v2_instagram_users.user_id = users.id  
        ORDER by v2_instagram_users.id DESC");
        $statement->execute();

        while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

            $username = $row['username'];
            $access_token = $row['instagram_access_token'];
            
            $count = 20; // number of images to show
            include 'lib/instagram_single.php';  //include instagram library 
    
    
?>

            <?php
            $ins_media = $insta->userMedia(); 
            $i = 0; 
            foreach ($ins_media['data'] as $vm): 
                if($count == $i){ break;}
                $i++;
                $img = $vm['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
                $link = $vm["link"];
            ?>
    
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" width="175" style="float:left;" />
                </a>
            <?php endforeach ?>
    
    <?php   
        }
    ?>
```

Anyone has any ideas why only one account is being displayed and their images when I have cour accounts in my database?

Comment: yeah, i just had it there for testing. unfortunaly that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Maybe you only get to make a limited number of requests.